# selenium difference between --headerless and -silent mode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I try selenium option argument in my PC, with either of modes (--headerless) or (--silent) it works fine. But on clients device it interrupts with strange code. I even added windows size after arguments, but error is same.`Error with Feature-Policy header`

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headerless')
webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
```

Comment: nope, `--headless'` is exact mode also `-silent` mode give same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The website with selenium  headless browser mode  detected as bot.
2. To avoid detection largely depends on `maximize_window_size()`
3. In your case,It's also need to add `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`

**The following example is working fine in Headless Chrome Selenium:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)
url = 'https://soundcloud.com/daydoseofhouse/snt-whats-wrong/s-jmbaiBDyQ0d?si=233b2f843a2c4a7c8afd6b9161369717&utm%5C_source=clipboard&utm%5C_medium=text&utm%5C_campaign=social%5C_sharing'
driver.get(url)

cookie = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()

video_duration = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="playbackTimeline__duration sc-text-primary sc-text-h5"]/span[2]'))).text

print(video_duration)
```

**Output:**

```
2:51
```

Comment: if class will change, will it work still? maybe not to enter whole classes but only one, that seems will not dissapear as a class from html body